# Can you calculate standard deviation with different variables?

Tags: physics, standard-deviation

I have a set of data that are basically used to plot points on a graph. When calculating standard deviation I have only ever calculated it with one variable. Is it possible to do it when there's a variable affecting the value you want to calculate the standard deviation for?
I have length and 1/Root(C) which we can call X for now:
example of the data:

```
length:x
0.1:0.139
0.2:0.288
0.6:1.052
```

Could I multiply each number by a value that makes there length = to the largest length (0.6) then use the mean of the values
example

```
0.1:0.139
```

becomes

```
0.6:0.834
```

Comment: I don't think this is at all clear.  What data are you trying to compute the standard deviation of?  What is $C$ and what has it got to do with anything?

Comment: @lulu C is count rate. Im just asking can I combine the two data items together because using different lengths is surely wrong

Comment: What two data items?  Length of what?  I think you assume your reader is aware of whatever you are working on....can you describe the problem clearly from the beginning?

Comment: @lulu its data i got from doing a physics practical to prove the gamma ray inverse square law. Length is the distance the source is from the counter and C is the count rate

Comment: Do you have a model of the data?  Something you are trying to fit to the data?  If so, you can hope to find optimal parameters for it.  It's easy to compute the standard deviation of any data you specify...but absent a model, it's really not clear what it is you are asking for.

Comment: @lulu not sure what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: I'm not sure what I could say that would help, I really have no idea what you are doing.  As a rule, statistics only helps when you have a clear model of what you think is going on.  If there are a bunch of unknowns and a bunch of unknown relations between them, statistics is of little value.  Might even hurt, as it is easy to find spurious relations in a haze of data.  All I can say at the start is:  if you can't ask a clear question, then you haven't got a good handle on the situation.

Comment: @lulu I honestly can't give you anymore information. It doesn't matter that much what the data is all I wanted to know is am I allowed the multiply the data so that the variable length is the same and then I can get the standard deviation from that. I can't use the 0.1m value with the 0.6m value because you can't get a mean from that